# Open Chrome with cookies set?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, cookies

How can I open Chrome to specific URL with cookies already set?

I don't mean cookies from an older session, I want to set the cookie(s) myself, similar to cURL's `--cookie` option.

e.g. something like:

```
google-chrome --cookie="FOO=BAR" https://example.org
```

Except `--cookie` doesn't appear to exist.

To be clear, I want to open a browser tab programatically and then give control back to the user. The user should not have to click anything to set the cookie.

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/fcapano/Edit-This-Cookie) project provide you with some insight as to how cookies can be programmatically managed?

Comment: @simlev No, I don't think so. That's a Chrome extension -- it has privileged access to the cookies. I want to set them externally... unless maybe I could boot Chrome into an extension or script where I can pass along the cookie to set.

Comment: What did you end up deciding? I have the exact same question!

Comment: @HipsterZipster Nothing. I gave up :'(

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Chrome does not have
[Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
for saving and loading cookies.
You need third-party software for that.

Windows users can use the free
[Nirsof ChromeCookiesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html)
which has a GUI interface but can also be used via the command line.
To load cookies :

```
ChromeCookiesView.exe /CookiesFile "c:\temp\Chrome\cookies"
```

ChromeCookiesView can save cookies in various formats,
but it is unclear what formats it can load (maybe all of them).

Otherwise, I can only recommend some Chrome extensions that can export and
import cookies :

- [Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookies/iphcomljdfghbkdcfndaijbokpgddeno?hl=en)
- [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)
- [J2TEAM Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/j2team-cookies/okpidcojinmlaakglciglbpcpajaibco?hl=en)

Comment: Hmm... I'm on Linux (Ubuntu). Wish ChromeCookiesView shared their source code, maybe I can hack whatever files Chrome uses to store the cookies...

Comment: If you're into programming, Chrome saves then in an SQLite database called "Cookies" containing a table called "cookies", and that's where all the extensions do their export/import. Their values might be encrypted if requested, so I hope yours aren't, but if they are then solutions exist and google for them.

Comment: You could create an sqlite3 file of commands that will import the cookies into the target. On the source you can select the table manually and export it to a file. You then distribute the two files, script and export file, and could launch sqlite3 to process them. There might be some complications to solve on the way, but this seems doable (if sqlite3 is installed).

Comment: I guess I'll try that then. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: `Nirsof ChromeCookiesView` detected as malware `PUA:Win32/Vigua.A` by `Windows Defender`.
I'm really afraid all my cookies stolen.

Comment: @AnasFanani: Defender doesn't like the Nirsof utilities, but they are not malware. I have used them for years without a problem, and I have set up an exception in Defender to the Nirsoft utilities folder, to have peace from Defender.